# Lion and Boot Camp Windows 7 cannot agree on a system time. What did I do wrong?

Tags: bootcamp, virtualization, timezone

I run Lion and Windows 7 on a MacBook, using Boot Camp and Parallels. Both operating systems are set to the same time zone and, presumably, use the same clock.

For some reason Windows 7 insists on being one hour wrong when running on the iron. Running as a VM under Lion Windows displays the same time as Lion.

Is this an issue of checking whether one of the OS thinks that it the hardware clock is set to GMT (I am one hour away from GMT)? Where would I find the setting?

Answer (score 1):

The OSes interpret the system's clock data differently - this has been an issue as long as Boot Camp has been available.

You might want to add a crontab to use ntpdate to update (-u) from your preferred NTP server, such as time.apple.com.

Comment: I just rebooted into Windows and now the time was the same in both systems. Odd.